# change font as well as size in listing

Tags: listings

I am including some R codes in my thesis using `listing`. I want to have the codes in `footnotesize` and in `ttfamily` font. I can get either of them by using `lstset{basicstyle=...}`. **But I cannot figure out how to get both of them. Is it even possible, please? Thanks.**

Comment: `basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Wonderful. I did not know I could do that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Will up-voting your comments increase your points?

Comment: No. I can add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple font and size switches to `basicstyle`, so just do

```
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
```